# AWS User Data on built server

Tags: amazon-web-services, scripting, user-data

Is it possible to obtain the AWS user data script that was run when an EC2 instance was built?

I know it's possible via the console, but is it possible to also retrieve the script that was run at the server level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the data like this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
```

run this on the instance

Comment: Thanks. I also found that it;s in file form in the following locations

Windows - Program Files/Amazon/Ec2ConfigService/Scripts
Linux - /var/lib/cloud/instance/